# scroll for child View Controllers swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i have a view that looks like instagram's home. scrolling should be like what you see in instagram but there is a problem with scrolling. when i try to scroll the view to down, only the collection view controller that is on the bottom scrolls and the top one sticks to where that is was. i tried to solve it with giving the frame's height of the bottom collectionviewcontroller to the container's frame's height but it does not work. this is the code:

```
var homeView = HomeView()
var newStoresViewController = HomeNewStoresCollectionViewController()
var elementsViewController = ElementsCollectionViewController()
```

and in load view:

```
homeView = Bundle.load()

homeView.newStoresBackgroundView.addFitSubview(newStoresViewController.view)
newStoresViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
addChildViewController(newStoresViewController)

homeView.elementsBackGroundView.addFitSubview(elementsViewController.view)
elementsViewController.willMove(toParentViewController: self)
addChildViewController(elementsViewController)
```

[homeView's xib image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlWVE.png)

thanks